# Include a file to an executable script, grab line 1 and line 2, assign them to data_holders

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, executable

Assume that there is a file named `a.txt`
which contains:

```
aaa
bbb
```

i need to create an executable script that
will grab these 2 lines from the a.txt

and then print them in the terminal.

in other words when i run..

```
./script
```

it needs to print

```
aaa:bbb
```

## UPDATE

i need to assign the first line from the file a.txt
to the letter "a"

i need to assign the second line from the file a.txt
to the letter "b"

so that i can access "a" and "b" within my bash script
separately.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the basics of shell programming and no attempt was made to provide an answer such as `read a; read b; echo "$a:$b"` which seems to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to do this:

```
awk '{printf $1":"}' a.txt
```

Comment: i wouldn't know how to modify that code.

Comment: what do you mean ? In detail please !

Comment: let's say first line becomes $a and second line becomes $b, how do i make it echo something like : ($a) ($b) ?  i need to separate them

Comment: i need to make first line become $a and second line become $b so i can echo them with different things around them.

Comment: Please edit your question and specify what exactly you want and what have you tried to receive specific answer